# Regular expression that can get tag with some text inside

Tags: regex

Here is my example:

```
<w:p>
<w:pPr>
    <w:spacing></w:spacing>
    <w:contextualSpacing/>
    <w:rPr/>
</w:pPr>
<w:r>
    <w:rPr>
        <w:color/>
        <w:rtl w:val="0"/>
    </w:rPr>
    <w:t>Some text</w:t>
</w:r>

<w:r>
    <w:rPr>
        <w:color/>
        <w:rtl/>
    </w:rPr>
    <w:t>My search text</w:t>
</w:r>

<w:r>
    <w:rPr>
        <w:color/>
        <w:rtl/>
    </w:rPr>
    <w:t>Other text</w:t>
</w:r>
```

I need to get this block with a regular expression:

```
<w:r>
    <w:rPr>
        <w:color/>
        <w:rtl/>
    </w:rPr>
    <w:t>My search text</w:t>
</w:r>
```

But my regular expression always get first `<w:r`> and last `</w:r>`. Lazy quantifiers don`t help.

So how I can get `<w:r> </w:r>` block only with "My search text" inside?

https://regex101.com/r/2Sh68k/2 Here is the example

Comment: What did you try to do? How did it fail? Why do you want to use regular expressions instead of a XML parser?

Comment: This is my example https://regex101.com/r/2Sh68k/2 .About XML parser, it is quite difficult to parse this xml (this is xml from DOCX format), so I suppose with regex it will be easier + I need to just find block and replace him by another

Comment: Why don't you just search for `My search text`, is the context relevant? If yes, add it to the expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here the steps to fix your example

```
<w:r>.+My search text.+<\/w:r>
```

adding a non captuiring group around the `.` of `.+` have no effect

```
<w:r>(?:.)+My search text(?:.)+<\/w:r>
```

inserting a negative lookahead `(?!)` before `.` to prevent the next matching chracter to be the start of not wanted sequence `<w:r>` or `</w:r>`

```
<w:r>(?:(?!<w:r>|<\/w:r>).)+My search text(?:(?!<w:r>|<\/w:r>).)+<\/w:r>
```

[updated link](https://regex101.com/r/2Sh68k/6)